# Countor plot of bivariate normal functions

Tags: r, ggplot2, normal-distribution

Could someone explain me why such function doesn't produce a countor plot as I expected.
I've a bivariate normal function whit:

- means = c(5,1)
- var_cov = matrix(c(2,1,1,1),2)

I'd like to plot its contour plot; I'm able to reach the result but I'd like to ask why in one case I don't get expected result.

*Working Example:*

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 100 
set.seed(123)

var_cov_matrix <- matrix(c(2,1,1,1),2)
mean <- c(5,1)

bivariate_points <- expand.grid(s.1 = seq(-25, 25, length.out=N), s.2 = seq(-25, 25, length.out=N))
z <- mvtnorm::dmvnorm(bivariate_points, mean = mean, sigma = var_cov_matrix)

data  <- cbind(bivariate_points,z)
colnames(data) <- c("X1","X2","Z")

data.df <- as.data.frame(data)

ggplot() +
  geom_contour(data=data.df,aes(x=X1,y=X2,z=Z))
```

*Non Working Example:*

```
library(MASS)
library(ggplot2)

N <- 100 
set.seed(123)

var_cov_matrix <- matrix(c(2,1,1,1),2)
mean <- c(5,1)

bivariate_points <- mvrnorm(N, mu = mean, Sigma = var_cov_matrix ) # <---- EDITED
z <- mvtnorm::dmvnorm(bivariate_points, mean = mean, sigma = var_cov_matrix)

data  <- cbind(bivariate_points,z)
colnames(data) <- c("X1","X2","Z")

data.df <- as.data.frame(data)

ggplot() +
  geom_contour(data=data.df,aes(x=X1,y=X2,z=Z))
```

Answer (score 1):

In your non-working example, since you don't have regular grid for contour plot, you can use `stat_density2d` instead, i.e.,

```
ggplot(data.df, aes(x = X1, y = X2, z = Z)) +
  geom_point(aes(colour = z)) +
  stat_density2d()
```

[image]